# Enter key behavior not working as expected in React onKeyDown event

Tags: reactjs, onkeydown

In my React application inside the text editor I have this code snippet:

```
onKeyDown={(e) => {
   console.log("e.code: ", e.code);
}}
```

When I hold **ShiftLeft **and then press **Enter **you then can see in logs that **ShiftLeft**, **Enter** are printed.
What I do not understand is that when I do exactly the same but while holding **ControlLeft**, the **Enter** is not printed.

I tried trying out different browsers on my windows but it is the same, on MacBook it works properly.
What could be the issue?

Comment: Works for me https://codesandbox.io/s/romantic-surf-9fjp3f?file=/src/App.js

Comment: Works for me too on Windows 10.